# How to check file names for duplication

Tags: php, wordpress, function, upload

I'm trying to make a random auto-name for uploaded files in WordPress, and i did it, but not completely. Look my code please.

I need to check new filenames  for duplication, and then return filename or generate new name, depend of check. But I do not know how to check filenames for duplication. Can you help me with it?

```
function new_upload_filename($filename, $filename_raw) {
    $info = pathinfo( $filename );
    $type = $info['extension'];
    if ( $type == 'jpg' || $type == 'jpeg' || $type == 'png' ) {
        $prefix = 'img_';
    } elseif ( $type == 'pdf' || $type == 'txt' || $type == 'docx' || $type == 'doc' || $type == 'xlsx' || $type == 'xls'  ) {
        $prefix = 'doc_';
    } elseif ( $type == 'mp4' || $type == 'avi' ) {
        $prefix = 'mov_';
    } elseif ( $type == 'gif' ) {
        $prefix = 'gif_';
    } else {
        $prefix = 'file_';
    }
    while ( $duplicatecheck ) {
    $ext  = empty( $info['extension'] ) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $rand = rand(11111,9999);
    $newname = $prefix . $rand . $ext;
    $duplicatecheck = // duplicate name checker (true if dublicate or false if not)
    return $newname;
} 
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'new_upload_filename', 10, 2);
```

Wordpress has a built-in check function, if the names are duplicated, then the duplicate gets the suffix -1 (++). But I do not know how to use it in my cheker.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_filename/

Thanks.

UPD:

Ready.

```
do {
$ext = empty( $info['extension'] ) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
$rand = rand(11111,9999);
$newname = $prefix . $rand . $ext;

    $upload_dir = wp_get_upload_dir();
    $namecheck =  is_file( $upload_dir['path'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $newname );

} while ( $namecheck );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an MD5 hash of Unix Date + filename + username + `uniqid`. Ask `is_file` if the file exists. If so, increment your hash and check again.

Alternatively, if your files are being referenced in a database somehow, you may be able to use the database_id as the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to parse through all of your files using something like [`readdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php), or save the generated names in a database as an array and loop through that.

Why not just generate a more linear filename using something like the current unix timestamp, so your risk of collisions is mitigated while they're being named?

```
$newname = $prefix . time() . $ext;
```

Or if you get multiple files per second, you can get identifying information from the user:

```
 $newname = $prefix . get_current_user_id() . time(). $ext;
```

Or if you're trying to obfuscate it a little bit, just run it through a basic hash like md5.

```
$hash = md5( get_current_user_id() . time() );
$newname = $prefix . $hash . $ext;
```